# FCam - pictures are coming out weird

Tags: c++, qt4, maemo, n900

I am writing an FCam application and any picture I take that has movement has a noticeable distortion.  I don't know if I'm using the API correctly or not.

It appears that the image is written from the top down.  So, if I walk around with the camera, every row below it is shifted over to the right or left (depending on the movement).  Is there anyway to 'freeze' the picture like normal cameras take?  I don't care about motion blur, that is fine.  Just this distortion won't work.

Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I used stream instead of capture.  A good bit of the documentation used stream and I figured I'd use that to follow things exactly.  After migrating, it works perfectly now.

Walter